# Arduino : How to write a variable value into a text file and modify it in the SD card?

Tags: arduino-uno, sd-card, string

I want to write a variable value into a text file in the SD card and modify it while reading if needed.
I found a text reading code which reads a desired line in the text file.(not tested)

//reading code

```
#include <SD.h>

int stepToLoad = 1;
int endOfLineNumber = 0;
int stepCount = 0;
int stringIndex = 0;
File configFile;
char inputString [1280];
char inputChar;

void setup() {
  stepToLoad = 13;
  if (!SD.begin(36)) {
    return;
  }

  if (SD.exists("config.txt")) {
    configFile = SD.open("config.txt");
    getStepCount();
    getStepData();
    configFile.close();
  }
}

void loop() {

}

void getStepData() {

  if (configFile) {
    while (configFile.available()) {
      inputChar = configFile.read(); // Gets one byte from serial buffer
      if (inputChar != '^') { // define breaking char here

        inputString[stringIndex] = inputChar; // Store it
        stringIndex++; // Increment where to write next

      } else {
        endOfLineNumber++;
        stringIndex++;
        if (endOfLineNumber == stepToLoad) { //this is the correct line to load


          break; //break out of the "while" loop
        } else { //not the correct line to load, reset and continue

          stringIndex = 0;
        }
      }

    }

  }
}

void getStepCount() {
  if (configFile) {
    while (configFile.available()) {
      inputChar = configFile.read(); // Gets one byte from serial buffer
      if (inputChar == '^') { // define breaking char here
        stepCount++;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know it is not possible to read a file and meanwhile change a value.

What normally is done is:

- Read the file
- Store it in memory
- Change the value in memory
- Write the file

However, since the SRAM memory is very limited, the following approach is better:

- For every buffer (512 bytes):

  - Read 512 bytes buffer
  - Change values in the buffer if needed
  - Write 512 bytes to another file
  - Until the end of the file to read is reached
- Remove the original file
- Change the name of the new file to the old file

Comment: You do not need to recopy the entire file, it is possible to simply read/modify/write the specific blocks containing the data to be changed.

Comment: @ChrisStratton True, but looking at the code from the OP, it also processes the entire file. But as you mention, it is not mandatory to read it completely or even sequentially.

Answer (score 1):

> How to write a variable value into a text file and modify it in the SD card?

This software design issue depends much on the chosen representation on file. In principle, there are two design dimensions. The first is textual or binary representation. The second is fixed or variable size records.

With textual representation (e.g. Serial.print) values are converted to text and stored on the file. The size of the record (e.g. line) depends on the number of characters needed for the value. New-line is often used as the record delimiter. To locate a specific record the file has to be scanned. There is no way to calculate the position of a record. When reading back the value the textual representation must be parsed and the internal representation in memory restored.

With binary representation (e.g. Serial.write) values are written directly from memory to the file. The size of the record is fixed as the size of a struct. Locating a specific record is easy; record index time record size. The SD library file.seek(position) is perfect to index the record. When reading the value back to memory there is no need for conversion as in textual representation.

It should be added that fixed size textual representation is also possible, e.g. make each line the same length by using a padding character (space, etc).

A text file with variable values is the more difficult as it is both textual representation and variable record. It is also the most inefficient as it requires compute power for the value representation conversions. The major advantage is that the text file can be generated with a ordinary text editor. No special tool or program is needed.

Binary file format with fixed records will require initialization.

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

It was super complicated for me at first but I understand it now. I'll upload just the DS3231 Code with the SD card functionality

```
#include <Wire.h>
#include <DS3231.h>
#include <SPI.h>
#include <SD.h>

DS3231 clock;
RTCDateTime dt;
File myFile;
String fileName = "000000.txt";

void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(9600);

  // Initialize DS3231
  Serial.println("Initialize DS3231");;
  clock.begin();

  // Set sketch compiling time
  clock.setDateTime(__DATE__, __TIME__);

  // Set from UNIX timestamp
  // clock.setDateTime(1397408400);

  // Manual (YYYY, MM, DD, HH, II, SS
  // clock.setDateTime(2016, 12, 9, 11, 46, 00);
}

void getName(){
  String date = clock.dateFormat("mdy", dt);
  fileName[0] = date[0];
  fileName[1] = date[1];
  fileName[2] = date[2];
  fileName[3] = date[3];
  fileName[4] = date[4];
  fileName[5] = date[5];
}

void sdCard() {
  if (!SD.begin(4)) {
    Serial.println("initialization failed!");
    while (1);
  }

  Serial.println("initialization done.");

  getName();

  myFile = SD.open(fileName, FILE_WRITE);

  if (myFile) {
    Serial.print("Writing to file...");
    myFile.println("testing 1, 2, 3.");
    Serial.println("done.");
  } 
  else {
    Serial.println("error opening file");
  }
}

void loop()
{
  dt = clock.getDateTime();


  Serial.print("Long number format:          ");
  Serial.println(clock.dateFormat("H:i:s", dt));

  sdCard();
  getName();

  myFile = SD.open(fileName, FILE_WRITE);
  myFile.println("Testing 1...2...3...")

}
```

So what I did here was initialize the variable for the text name with placeholders and I used the date in a 6 digit format. Both variables being a string, I can set the first position of the text name to be the first position of the date. So all values are replaced. Should be the same thing for an 8 digit text name, but after that there is a limit, not including the file extension.

Comment: It's not clear that this answers the question asked, in large part because the question is unanswerably unclear, and needs to be closed.